# I don't know why this code does line breaking by itself

Tags: java, line-breaks

I devided this code into three parts; Main, DisSystem, DisIndexerUI.
Its purpose is to calculate a Discomfort Index. The calculation system works perfectly, but I find out that the printed result has something wrong. This is the result:

```
input temperature
36
input humidity
42    
Discomfort Index:96.75999999999999    
Very very uncomfortable    
It is
```

I think it should print "It is very very uncomfortable", but the result I printed is

```
Very very uncomfortable    
It is
```

It's a very weird situation. I would like to know why it happens.

Of course I know that, if I fix it like this:

```
    System.out.println("Discomfort Index:"+ ui.input());
    System.out.print("It is ");
    ui.status();
```

It will print "It is Very very uncomfortable".
But it is only a temporary solution, I think. Why is it line breaking ?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double temp = 0;
    double humidity = 0;

    DisSystem dis = new DisSystem();
    DisIndexerUI ui = new DisIndexerUI(dis);

    System.out.println("Discomfort Index:"+ ui.input());
    System.out.println("It is" + ui.status());

}
}    
==================================
public class DisSystem {    

public static double Formula(double temp, double humidity) {
    double formula = 0.72 * (temp + humidity) + 40.6;
    return formula;
}

    }    
=================================
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DisIndexerUI {
DisSystem disSystem;
double formula = 0;

public DisIndexerUI(DisSystem disSystem) {
    this.disSystem = disSystem;
}

public double input() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input temperature");
    double temp = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("input humidity");
    double humidity = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
    formula = disSystem.Formula(temp, humidity);
    return formula;
}

public String status() {
    String str = "";
    if (formula >= 86) {
        System.out.println("Very very uncomfortable");
    } else if (formula >= 83) {
        System.out.println("Very uncomfortable");
    } else if (formula >= 80) {
        System.out.println("uncomfortable");
    } else if (formula >= 75) {
        System.out.println("nomal");
    } else if (formula >= 70) {
        System.out.println("good");
    } else if (formula >= 68) {
        System.out.println("very good");
    }
    return str;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at `status()` and then think about what you expect it to do (I'd assume return the status string) and what it actually does (print the status string and return an empty string). Additionally fire up a debugger and see for yourself (learning to do this will help a lot in the future).

Comment: think about "why is `status()` returning an **empty**  String?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick fix:**

Replace `System.out.println("It is" + ui.status());` with `ui.status()`;

Make `System.out.print("It is ");` as first statement in `status` method.

**Better way:** Follow Thomas's advice - comment on question.

**Edit:**

Actually, the code isn't breaking, its behaving as expected.

In the `main` method, a call is made to `System.out.println("It is" + ui.status());`. The point to note here is that `status` method will first execute and return a value. Then, the returned value(which is empty string as declared in that method) will be concatenated with the string - "It is". So, when execution jumps to `status` method, you are printing strings depending on conditions. So, first any of those strings will be printed then, a value will be returned. Hence, you are seeing the output which is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You just return an empty string in the `status` method, but print the actual value.

```
public String status() {
    if (formula >= 86) {
        return "Very very uncomfortable";
    } else if (formula >= 83) {
        return "Very uncomfortable";
    } else if (formula >= 80) {
        return "uncomfortable";
    } else if (formula >= 75) {
        return "nomal";
    } else if (formula >= 70) {
        return "good";
    } else if (formula >= 68) {
        return "very good";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Furthermore check whether the empty string in the else statement is correct for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **System.out.println("Text");** which move the cursor to the next line after printing the string. if you want the string to be in the same line via multiple print statement then use **System.out.print("Text");**.

Comment: If the author follows this lead he will end up with a result of "Very very uncomfortableIt is". I don't think that this is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
System.out.println("It is" + ui.status());
```

makes a call to *status* member of *DisIndexerUI* instance *ui* which first prints the the literal and a line breaker then returns empty string which is concatenated to the first operand and then the evaluated *"It is" + ""* is printed. Changing the status() method of DisIndexerUI to return the literal instead of printing it will fix the issue.

```
public String status() {
    String str = "";
    if (formula >= 86) {
        str = "Very very uncomfortable";
    } else if (formula >= 83) {
        str = "Very uncomfortable";
    } else if (formula >= 80) {
        str = "uncomfortable";
    } else if (formula >= 75) {
        str = "nomal";
    } else if (formula >= 70) {
        str = "good";
    } else if (formula >= 68) {
        str = "very good";
    }
    return str;

}
```